# sql query only update if not a duplicate of a non-primary row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a very simple SQL Query in php.  After someone creates their username, they can go and edit it  to something else.

```
$uName_str = "UPDATE users SET users.username = '{$newUserName}' WHERE users.username = '{$oldUserName}';
```

But I don't want them to be able to update their username to the same username as someone else.  The primary key is the userID.  I could run a separate query to look for all usernames, then compare the newly selected username against the database of usernames, but an entirely separate query for one thing seems inefficient.  Is there any way to write this as a single query so that any duplicate entries are prevented?

Comment: make `username` field unique in database, if when you update it returns the error preventing changing you can show the error message already

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All you need:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE INDEX(username);

$uName_str = "UPDATE IGNORE users SET users.username = '{$newUserName}' WHERE users.username = '{$oldUserName}';
```

Comment: Why are some of these answers downvoted?  This answer works fine.

Comment: Looks like someone really wanted the points so bad that they wanted to downvote other comments. lol Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a unique index on the username column.  Then check for errors/exceptions on update.

Answer (score 1):

Please add `username` as an unique index. After that you'll get a MySQL error if someone tries to duplicate the entry:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD UNIQUE(`username`);
```

Answer (score -2):

It wouldn't be considered inefficient to run a simple query to check if a username is taken. It would be considered best practice. You could make a stored procedure also. But that is a bit more complex solution. I wouldn't recommend Rob's answer. Since it will fill your error log with exceptions making you believe it's errors when it's really just usernames that are taken.

Comment: Thanks, a stored procedure is a bit beyond me at this point.  I'll try both out and see which one works better for my needs.

Comment: It doesn't throw a fatal error.  It's just a triggered error or exception that you catch in your code and deal with.  It's the best way to handle this situation.

Comment: Rob's solution is good, the triggered exception gives me the ability to display an error message to the user that the username they wish to choose has already been good.